Bosch PSB 650 RE Hammer Drill spindle lock button broke
The spindle lock button on my Bosch PSB 650 RE Hammer Drill is damaged and  dislodged and I cannot get it to lock the spindle. Is it repairable?

Spindle locks are just a pin that is pushed in.  Nothing too fancy, just something for us idiots to break.  Bosch might have a repair part for it, but till you get a new one and need it, removing all the parts and finding a a pin(nail, pin punch, bolt) and remember to remove it this time.
